# Proper API calls and server-side data storage - Blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor, api-design, web-development-server

I'm trying to learn Blazor while bringing some of my ideas to live as I think that the best way to learn is by practice. I want to build a card viewer for CCG (collectible card game) and I've stumbled upon a roadblock which I hope someone can help me with :)

As I don't want to store the card database myself, I'm using a 3rd party source to download the required information - and I have a problem with it's storage afterwards.
I made a server-side controller that fetches the mentioned DB (after some sorting with my own class to filter some unnecesarry data). What I wanted to achieve is a list of all the cards and onClick to fetch the info about the specific one by ID.

My controller looks like this:

```
[Route("[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CardController : ControllerBase
{
    private List<Card> Cards = new();

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public ActionResult Get(int id)
    {
        var card = Cards.Find(o => o.Id == id);

        if (card != null)
        {
            return Ok(card);
        }

        return NotFound("Card not found");
    }

    [HttpGet("List")]
    public ActionResult List()
    {
        return Ok(Cards);
    }

    [HttpGet("GetAllCards")]
    public async Task<List<Card>> GetAllCards()
    {
        if (Cards.Count() == 0)
        {
            Cards = await GetAllCardsPro();
        }

        return Cards;
    }
    public async Task<List<Card>> GetAllCardsPro()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();

        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://db.ygoprodeck.com/api/v7/cardinfo.php");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        YgoProMap.Rootobject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YgoProMap.Rootobject>(responseBody);

        if (obj != null)
        {
            foreach (var card in obj.data)
            {
                Cards.Add(new Card
                {
                    Id = card.id,
                    Name = card.name,
                    Type = card.type,
                    Desc = card.desc,
                    Atk = card.atk,
                    Def = card.def,
                    Level = card.level,
                    Race = card.race,
                    Attribute = card.attribute,
                    Archetype = card.archetype,
                    Linkval = card.linkval,
                    Scale = card.scale,
                    Images = new string[] { card.card_images.First().image_url, card.card_images.First().image_url_small }
                });
            }
        }

        return Cards;
    }
}
```

The problem occurs when I try to call **Get(ID)** to get info of that specific card and it always return 404. If I manualy populate the Cards list with a **new Card(some data)** I'm able to get that one specific card's information. So I would assume that after the call to that 3rd party API Cards it just passes the value to client once remaining null on the server.

So my 1st question here is how should I store that data that is fetched from the 3rd party API to make it accessable afterwards? Should it be somewhere in the server startup with a daily refresh? Is it even possible to store it like a JSON file for example?

My 2nd question is about best practices performance wise as at the moment I'm passing the whole **List of Cards** to the client (~10 thousand objects). Would it be better to pass a separate array that only stores **card.Name** and **card.Id** for it to be bound to a UI list/table and afterwards onClick fetch that specific card's full data? Or 10 thousand objects isn't a huge deal and I should just pass the whole List and do all the specific card operation client side?

Sorry for making it so long but I've tried to be as specific as I can :D

Comment: `Controller` objects are created **and destroyed** for each incoming HTTP request. All data in `Controller` instance state (i.e. fields) will be lost between requests. Additionally, `Controller` instances are not shared between requests, i.e. each request gets its own distinct `Controller` instance object. Ergo, `Controller` objects should not (and cannot) be used to persist state between requests. Consider using `MemoryCache` for quick-and-dirty in-memory persistence (though their data will still be lost when your application is restarted or recycled). You should just use a normal RDMBS.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to have "list", "add" (`GET` and `POST`) and "edit" (`GET` and `POST`) actions in the _same_ single `Controller` class. As your project grows you'll inevitably end-up with separate `Controller` classes for each action-pair (`GET` and `POST`) and another one for the "list" action. YMMV.